# How to erase canvas on click of erase button by using sketch.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I used `sketch.min.js` file from [here](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/). In this by clicking on Eraser link should erase the canvas.

Because I don't want to click twice on eraser link and on canvas, I need if click on eraser link should erase canvas.

Code I used like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="tools">
      <a href="#tools_sketch" data-tool="marker">Marker</a>
      <a href="#tools_sketch" data-tool="eraser">Eraser</a>
    </div>
    <canvas id="tools_sketch" width="800" height="300" style="background:#eee;"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __slice = Array.prototype.slice;
        (function(a) {
            var b;
            return a.fn.sketch = function() {
                var c, d, e;
                d = arguments[0],
                c = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [],
                this.length > 1 && a.error("Sketch.js can only be called on one element at a time."),
                e = this.data("sketch");
                if (typeof d != "string" || !e)
                    return e ? e : (this.data("sketch", new b(this.get(0),d)),
                    this);
                if (!e[d])
                    return a.error("Sketch.js did not recognize the given command.");
                if (typeof e[d] == "function")
                    return e[d].apply(e, c);
                if (c.length === 0)
                    return e[d];
                if (c.length === 1)
                    return e[d] = c[0]
            }
            ,
            b = function() {
                function b(b, c) {
                    this.el = b,
                    this.canvas = a(b),
                    this.context = b.getContext("2d"),
                    this.options = a.extend({
                        toolLinks: !0,
                        defaultTool: "marker",
                        defaultColor: "#134543",
                        defaultSize: 3
                    }, c),
                    this.painting = !1,
                    this.color = this.options.defaultColor,
                    this.size = this.options.defaultSize,
                    this.tool = this.options.defaultTool,
                    this.actions = [],
                    this.action = [],
                    this.canvas.bind("click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel", this.onEvent),
                    this.options.toolLinks && a("body").delegate('a[href="#' + this.canvas.attr("id") + '"]', "click", function(b) {
                        var c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
                        d = a(this),
                        c = a(d.attr("href")),
                        f = c.data("sketch"),
                        i = ["color", "size", "tool"];
                        for (g = 0,
                        h = i.length; g < h; g++)
                            e = i[g],
                            d.attr("data-" + e) && f.set(e, a(this).attr("data-" + e));
                        return a(this).attr("data-download") && f.download(a(this).attr("data-download")),!1
                    })
                }
                return b.prototype.download = function(a) {
                    var b;
                    return a || (a = "png"),
                    a === "jpg" && (a = "jpeg"),
                    b = "image/" + a,
                    window.open(this.el.toDataURL(b))
                }
                ,
                b.prototype.set = function(a, b) {
                    return this[a] = b,
                    this.canvas.trigger("sketch.change" + a, b)
                }
                ,
                b.prototype.startPainting = function() {
                    return this.painting = !0,
                    this.action = {
                        tool: this.tool,
                        color: this.color,
                        size: parseFloat(this.size),
                        events: []
                    }
                }
                ,
                b.prototype.stopPainting = function() {
                    return this.action && this.actions.push(this.action),
                    this.painting = !1,
                    this.action = null ,
                    this.redraw()
                }
                ,
                b.prototype.onEvent = function(b) {
                    return b.originalEvent && b.originalEvent.targetTouches && (b.pageX = b.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX,
                    b.pageY = b.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY),
                    a.sketch.tools[a(this).data("sketch").tool].onEvent.call(a(this).data("sketch"), b),
                    b.preventDefault(),
                    !1
                }
                ,
                b.prototype.redraw = function() {
                    var b;
                    this.el.width = this.canvas.width(),
                    this.context = this.el.getContext("2d"),
                    b = this,
                    a.each(this.actions, function() {
                        if (this.tool)
                            return a.sketch.tools[this.tool].draw.call(b, this)
                    });
                    if (this.painting && this.action)
                        return a.sketch.tools[this.action.tool].draw.call(b, this.action)
                }
                ,
                b
            }(),
            a.sketch = {
                tools: {}
            },
            a.sketch.tools.marker = {
                onEvent: function(a) {
                    switch (a.type) {
                    case "mousedown":
                    case "touchstart":
                        this.startPainting();
                        break;
                    case "mouseup":
                    case "mouseout":
                    case "mouseleave":
                    case "touchend":
                    case "touchcancel":
                        this.stopPainting()
                    }
                    if (this.painting)
                        return this.action.events.push({
                            x: a.pageX - this.canvas.offset().left,
                            y: a.pageY - this.canvas.offset().top,
                            event: a.type
                        }),
                        this.redraw()
                },
                draw: function(a) {
                    var b, c, d, e, f;
                    this.context.lineJoin = "round",
                    this.context.lineCap = "round",
                    this.context.beginPath(),
                    this.context.moveTo(a.events[0].x, a.events[0].y),
                    f = a.events;
                    for (d = 0,
                    e = f.length; d < e; d++)
                        b = f[d],
                        this.context.lineTo(b.x, b.y),
                        c = b;
                    return this.context.strokeStyle = a.color,
                    this.context.lineWidth = a.size,
                    this.context.stroke()
                }
            },
            a.sketch.tools.eraser = {
                onEvent: function(b) {
                    return a.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, b)
                },
                draw: function(b) {
                    var c;
                    return c = this.context.globalCompositeOperation,
                    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy",
                    b.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                    a.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, b),
                    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = c
                }
            }
        })(jQuery)

      $(function() {
        $('#tools_sketch').sketch({defaultColor: "#ff0"});
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Although high level English is not expected here, following a [minimal set of the spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is gladly welcomed.

Comment: Please, can any one solve this.

Comment: Did you read the link I've wrote?

Comment: Yes thank you for English corrections..

Comment: Ok. Please follow them in the future. | I think, you didn't get an answer until now, because it requires more work as actual knowledge. But it is not so hard to answer. Currently there is Sunday, and few are using the Stackoverlfow, but tomorrow you will have probably a much better chance.

Comment: Yes, I got solution..

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a solution for my question:

Just put this code `if(f.tool=="eraser"){ f.startPainting();}` after this line of code `d.attr("data-" + e) && f.set(e, a(this).attr("data-" + e));`.

Comment: Good answer! But it would be more better if you would explain, why this is the solution and how does it work.

Comment: Note, "I" is always uppercase in English.

Comment: Note, don't forget to accept also your own answer to your own question.